# Using eve to limit user access

Tags: flask, eve

I have two different objects in my API, we can call them users as tasks.  I want to shape the API so users can only access tasks associated with them, but admin can access all tasks.  How would I check to make sure what they are requesting matches their username?  I have login working as per http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/building-rest-apis-using-eve--cms-22961 but I'd like to be able to create a more encompassing API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might resort to [User Restricted Resource Access](http://python-eve.org/authentication.html#user-restricted-resource-access)

> When this feature is enabled, each stored document is associated with the account that created it. **This allows the API to transparently serve only account-created documents** on all kinds of requests: read, edit, delete and of course create. User authentication needs to be enabled for this to work properly.

See the relevant documentation at the link above.

Comment: How does one achieve "admin" has access to all the tasks ? I too have similar requirement (Not addressed yet myself, but considering explicit logic by writing my own Auth Class, something like "if resource == tasks and user.role == admin: return True else
self.set_request_auth_value(user['id'])" Will that work ?